# Using information from a previous page on a new page with JS

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm new to Javascript and I need help figuring out this process, or at least figuring out what methods to use.  I don't really need a full solution, just some advice on what direction to go in.

I have a page with a list of links.  When a user clicks on any of the links, they are directed to the same html page ("park.html").  However, that page will be filled with different information based on which link the user clicks.  I will populate "parks.html" with info using a JSON and Javascript, but I just need some type of identifier to be supplied to "park.html" that will be different depending on which link is clicked.

I'm not sure whether to use event listeners, cookies, or possibly React?  I tried giving each link an event listener which calls a function that uses "event.target.innerHTML" to get the text of the link the user clicked on.  I've also tried running that function onload of "park.html", but I don't know how to pass information from the link clicked to that function call.

This is my code that creates the list of links.  "Entry" is drawn from a JSON file -- the list is being created correctly.

```
function appendToList(entry, resultsList) {
    let listElement = document.createElement("li");
    let listLink = document.createElement("a");
    listLink.setAttribute("href", "park.html");
    listLink.setAttribute("id", entry.fullName);
    listLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.fullName));

    listLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
        qVal = listLink.id;
        console.log(qVal);
        get_park_data(qVal);
    });

    listElement.appendChild(listLink);
    resultsList.appendChild(listElement);
    return resultsList;
}
```

I think the function that the listener calls (get_park_data) is running correctly, but runs on the page that the list is on -- not the page that the list elements link to.

So, how do I get an identifier of which link was clicked to be supplied to the page that is called?

I'd appreciate any insight! Thanks!

Comment: One basic solution would be to have a  unique data attribute value on each of the links, and when you click on that link, store the value as a cookie. Then just get that cookie value and search the dom for it when you load your page. Not sure what these links contain, but say you are selecting from a list of people, store the unique id for the person as the data attribute. That way, if you need to get data from a database or an api, you can also use that same unique id to do the db /api query.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use query parameters in the URL? It's pretty much easier. You'll just have to append it to the URL and you can change it everytime a user clicks a link.

Comment: Sounds like a solid solution, I'll give it a try! Thanks!